# Shell Script to delete specific image-files recursively

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I do have a third-party program, which uploads files to a webserver. These files are images, in different folders and with different names. Those files get references into a database. The program imports new images and upload those to those folders. If there is an existing file, it just takes the name and add a special counter, create a new reference in the database and the old one will be removed. But instead of removing the file as well, it keeps a copy.

Lets say, we have a image-file name "109101.jpg".
There is a new version of the file and it will be uploaded with the filename: "109101_1.jpg". This goes further till "109101_103.jpg" for example.
Now, all the 103 files before this one are outdated and could be deleted.

Due to the fact, that the program is not editable and third-party, I am not able to change that behavior. Instead, I need a Shell script, which walks through those folders and deletes all the images before the latest one. So only "109101_103.jpg" will survive and all the others before this number will be deleted.
And as a side effect, there are also images, with a double underscored name (only these, no tripple ones or so).
For example: "109013_35_1.jpg" is the original one, the next one is "109013_35_1_1.jpg" and now its at "109013_35_1_24.jpg". So only "109013_35_1_24.jpg" has to survive.

Right now I am not even having an idea, how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one line pipeline, because I felt like it. Shown with newlines inserted because I'm not evil.

```
for F in $(find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec basename {} .jpg \;
             | sed -r -e 's/^([^_]+|[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_[0-9]+$/\1/'
             | sort -u); do
    find -regex ".*${F}_[0-9]*.jpg" 
       | sort -t _ -k 2 -n | sort -n -t _ -k 4 -s | head -n -1;
done
```

Comment: This seems to work! I have to check it on the live system on Monday! Of course I will mark it as complete then. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following script deletes the files in a given directory:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd $1
shopt -s extglob                                       # Turn on extended patterns.
shopt -s nullglob                                      # Non matched pattern expands to null.
delete=()
for file in               +([^_])_+([0-9]).jpg \
        +([^_])_+([0-9])_+([0-9])_+([0-9]).jpg ; do    # Only loop over non original files.
    [[ $file ]] || continue                            # No files in the directory.
    base=${file%_*}                                    # Delete everything after the last _.
    num=${file##*_}                                    # Delete everything before the last _.
    num=${num%.jpg}                                    # Delete the extension.
    [[ -f $base.jpg ]] && rm $base.jpg                 # Delete the original file.
    [[ -f "$base"_$((num+1)).jpg ]] && delete+=($file) # The file itself is scheduled for deletion.
done
(( ${#delete[@]} )) && rm "${delete[@]}"
```

The numbered files are not deleted immediately, because that could remove a "following" file for another file. They are just remembered in an array and deleted at the end.

To apply the script recursively, you can run

```
find /top/directory -type d -exec script.sh {} \;
```

Comment: It throws an error: "script.sh: line 11: +([0-9]): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[0-9])")"

Comment: Well, after the error, some of the worked. I used a copied version of the folders and tried it out, but it deleted the wrong ones.

Comment: @KeenoraFluffball: what version of bash do you have? Have you copied and pasted the script from here? I am getting no syntax errors.

Comment: Its "GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)" But though, it gets the wrong files

Comment: @KeenoraFluffball: I updated the script. It was throwing the errors if there was a directory with no numbered files in it.

Comment: @KeenoraFluffball: Another updated. The script was deleting 1_1_1 if 1_1_2 was present, which is not correct.